# How do I add an Enterprise Custom Field to a view in Sharepoint/PWA?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, view, project-server, pwa

I have set up a number of new Enterprise Custom Fields and I would like to add these to a custom view in PWA.  However, when I try and create a new view my newly created Enterprise Custom Fields do not appear in the available fields.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of the Enterprise Custom Fields will be listed in the `Available Fields` section in the view

[image]

Based on the Enterprise Custom Field **Entity** and the **View Type**

[image]

**Eg:** if your view type is '`Resources Center`'. in this case the Custome fields with `Resource Entity` like `RBS` will be available within the `Available fields` section and other custom fields will not be listed.